# cannot cast 'void' to 'android.widget.Button'

Tags: android

I try to learn app development for Android, I'm new to it.
I recreated what they showed at the tutorial, but my code won't work. First I  created a button at the design view in android studio, then I should copied the code to give the button the funtion to send an intent to the camera.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);


        }
    });
}
```

Even if I copied the code, I get the error Message "cannot cast void to android widget button".

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your *tutorial* was trying to do this but in *fewer* lines:

```java
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button); // <-- object that belongs the view - the Button
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
  }
});
```

### However, you missed a bracket:

```java
((Button) findViewById(R.id.button) // <-- missing ")"
```

Should be:

```java
((Button) findViewById(R.id.button))
```

### Here is all of your code:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      startActivityForResult(i, 0);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missed a bracket in your tutorial

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

((Button)findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);


    }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a view with an id of button.  Create one in your activity_main layout.

Answer (score 0):

In `R.layout.activity_main` you need an `R.id.button` widget. Also make sure you do a clean build every time you modify your layout XML. It's important!